# Select first row in a filtered range using c# and Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an excel ws and need to select a range in a first visible row in a filtered range.
So I filter xlRangeInputComplete by "parente", set the visible range and define the range on the first visible row of filtered range.

```
Range xlRangeInputComplete = wsInput.UsedRange;
foreach (String parente in lparenti)
{        
    xlRangeInputComplete.AutoFilter(codiceParenteCol, parente);
    visibleRange = xlRangeInputComplete.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

    // Problem is in following line, I suppose
    rigaInput = visibleRange.Range[(Range)visibleRange.Cells[2, 1], (Range)visibleRange.Cells[2, colCount]];

    rigaOutput = wsOutput.Range[(Range)wsOutput.Cells[rigaDest, 1], (Range)wsOutput.Cells[rigaDest, colCount]];

   rigaInput.Copy(Type.Missing);
   rigaOutput.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
}
```

But always select the hidden 2 row in worksheet[image]

Please someone can help me?